# Is all kosher wine automatically kosher for Passover?

Tags: passover, grapes-wine

What could make a kosher wine not kosher for Passover?

The o-u site has a page saying, "Kosher for Passover ONLY when bearing special certification" (https://oukosher.org/product-search/ do a search on wine and check the passover box to see this page).

What about the production of wine could make it hametz?

Comment: Adding wheat would seem to do the trick

Comment: @DoubleAA  I do not know much about wine making.  Is wheat likely to be (or ever) added during wine production?

Comment: Yehuda, have you ever seen a hechshered wine without a Pessach hech'?

Comment: kosher an hechsher is not yhe same. wine is bottled before pesach, if there was a little quantity of chamets, it's bsyel before pesach, there is no taste of chamets in the wine

Comment: @YehudaW I don't know if it's likely, but it's certainly possible which answers your question.

Comment: When I visited Royal Wineries (aka Kedem), the guide, there, explained that no chametz is allowed anywhere on the grounds except in a one designated house away from the growing area, the production area and the bottling area and taste rooms, etc. Employees must go there to eat their lunch. Before re-entering the work area, an inspector checks their hands, faces and beards to make sure there are no chametz (bread) crumbs around. One person who violated the rule was immediately fired. IIRC, visitors were not allowed to bring any food on their grounds. So if you visit them, eat in your car.

Answer (score 2):

Real wine is fermented grapes and nothing else. Wine needs a hecksher as it has to be supervised by an observant jew.  All kosher wines I have seen have been labeled K-P, but the P isn't necessary. Manischewitz is the exception.  It is made in Canandaigua NY from grapes which due to the short growing season, do not have enough sugar to properly ferment, so the company adds hi-fructose corn syrup to make it sweeter. For Pesach they add cane sugar instead of HF Corn Syrup and it is labeled as K-p. It's pretty awful in either case.
BTW, Manischewitz is no longer owned by Manischewitz, which doesn't exist either. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manischewitz

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Rachel! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Adding some sources regarding the contents of wine, particularly those that address traces that could be halakhically significant, would improve this post.

Comment: while it is true the main ingredient of wine is grape juice there are chemicals added as part of the process. those include at minimum yeast and yeast nutrient. Some other ingredients which could be used but not necessarily used are potassium metabisulfite for killing unwanted yeasts and bacteria, acids, malolactic bacteria, fining agent, yeast energizer, potassium sorbate for stabilizing,

Comment: I had always called Manischewitz Malaga "pancake syrup". People thought I was crazy. Thanks for confirming for me that I'm not. Corn syrup - I never knew! You may want to edit your answer that the addition of corn syrup per se, makes it *kitniyot* which would make it prohibited by most Ashkenazim, not Sefardim. However, it is not *chametz* based on that, alone. OU and many other U.S. kashrut organizations automatically do not certify kitniot ingredients for Passover use.